# Get durations from time series table where some condition holds consecutively

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, window-functions

Given a table where each row has a timestamp and some measurement, how can I get all of the intervals during which the measurement consecutively satisfies some condition?

Here's a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad8d1/1) (not sure if there's a better site for that nowadays).

So in this case, I'd like to to get all of the durations during which `status` is true. The starting point should be the first true point chronologically. The end point can be the first false point or the last true point, whichever is easier.

I looked to window functions first. I could come up with separate queries, one that obtained the starting points and one that produced the end points, but it felt like I was going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try along:

```
SELECT
  ts
  , CASE status
      WHEN false THEN 'end'
      WHEN true THEN 'start'
      ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS mode
FROM (
  SELECT
    ts
    , status
    , LAG(status, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS lg
  FROM log
) AS T
WHERE
  (lg IS NULL)
  OR
  (status <> lg)
ORDER BY ts
;
```

The sub-select is necessary as window functions are not allowed directly in the `WHERE` clause.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad8d1/3) (Thanks for preparing the fiddle! ;-) )

### Update

To get the duration actually listed, try

```
WITH
S1 AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , status
    , LAG(status, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS lg
    , CASE status WHEN LAG(status, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ts) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS toggle 
  FROM log
  ORDER BY ts
),
S2 AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , status
    , lg
    , SUM(toggle) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS streak
  FROM S1
  ORDER BY ts
),
S3 (ts, last_ts, status, lg, streak) AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , LAST_VALUE(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY streak
                           ORDER BY ts
                           RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                          )
    , status
    , lg
    , streak
  FROM S2
  ORDER BY ts
),
S4 (start, duration) AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , last_ts - ts
  FROM S3
  WHERE
    status
    AND ((status <> lg) OR (lg IS NULL))
  ORDER BY ts
),
S5 (ts, status, duration) AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , status
    , LEAD(ts, 1, (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM S3)) OVER (ORDER BY ts) - ts
  FROM S3
  WHERE
    (status <> lg)
    OR
    (lg IS NULL)
  ORDER BY ts
),
S6 (start, duration) AS (
  SELECT
    ts
    , duration
  FROM S5
  WHERE status
)
SELECT
--  * FROM S4
  * FROM S6
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad8d1/4)

It starts off by identifying the consecutive ranges. In S4, the ranges end when **status** is **TRUE** for the last time respectively; in S6 when **status** changed to **FALSE**.

This could probably be condensed a little bit. But as window functions cannot be nested (directly) anyway…

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but what I want is for each row result to be a duration, e.g. '5 hours', possibly in the form of a `TSRANGE` type or `INTERVAL` or whatever is appropriate. Sorry if this was unclear.